# Error on executing trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PROCESS_POPULATE_INSTANCE
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON PROCESS_INSTANCE
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 InstanceExists NUMBER;
BEGIN
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 INTO InstanceExists
 FROM TEST_PROCESSDATA
 WHERE TEST_PROCESSDATA.PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = :NEW.INSTANCE_ID ;

 IF ( InstanceExists > 0 ) THEN
UPDATE TEST_PROCESSDATA SET PROCESS_STATUS =:NEW.STATUS WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = NEW.INSTANCE_ID;
 ELSIF 
 INSERT INTO TEST_PROCESSDATA (PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID,PROCESS_STATUS, STARTED_TIME) VALUES (:NEW.INSTANCE_ID,:NEW.STATUS,:NEW.START_TIME);
 END IF;
END PROCESS_POPULATE_APPDATA;
```

On executing the above trigger, i get the below error:

> Error(12,2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INSERT" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql
>   stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
>   date     
>    pipe    
>   Error(13,2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END"

Comment: Syntax error guys. Sorry. I have fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what [Ravindra bagale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776411/997660) has already noted I would add the following:

First. In the statement

```
UPDATE TEST_PROCESSDATA SET PROCESS_STATUS =:NEW.STATUS 
 WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = NEW.INSTANCE_ID;
```

`:` colon is missing in front of `NEW.INSTANCE_ID`

And second. You might consider using of `merge` statement instead of `IF .. THEN .. ELSE.. END IF` construct and additional `select` statement. For example.

```
create or replace trigger process_populate_instance     
after insert or update on process_instance 
for each row
begin

   merge into test_processdata
   using dual
     on (process_instance_id = :new.instance_id)
   when matched
    then update
            set process_status =:new.status
   when not matched
   then insert (process_instance_id,process_status, started_time) 
        values (:new.instance_id,:new.status,:new.start_time);

end;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ELSE instead of ELSIF`
here u used elseif,but not used else, u can't use elseif without else
when there are more than two way then u can use elsif.

```
IF ( InstanceExists > 0 ) THEN
UPDATE TEST_PROCESSDATA SET PROCESS_STATUS =:NEW.STATUS WHERE PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = NEW.INSTANCE_ID;
 ELSE 
 INSERT INTO TEST_PROCESSDATA (PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID,PROCESS_STATUS, STARTED_TIME) VALUES (:NEW.INSTANCE_ID,:NEW.STATUS,:NEW.START_TIME);
 END IF;
END PROC
```